# For fixed $\lambda \ge 0$, Integrate the function $f_\lambda(x):=x/(x + \lambda)^2$ w.r.t. Marchenko-Pastur density

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, integral-transforms, free-probability

In trying to solve another the problem posed in the question https://www.mathoverflow.net/q/385777/78539, I'm led to consider the following problem.

Let $\mu_\gamma$ be the Marchenko-Pastur distribution with parameter $\gamma \in (0,1)$. Note that $\mu_\gamma$ is supported on $[t_-,t_+]$, where $t_{\pm} = (1\pm \sqrt{\gamma})^2$. For $\lambda \ge 0$, define
$$
I_\gamma(\lambda):=\int_{t_-}^{t_+} \dfrac{t}{(t + \lambda)^2}d\mu_\gamma(t).
$$ It is clear that $I_\gamma$ is a decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$.

> **Question 1.** What is an analytic formula for $I_\gamma(\lambda)$ ?

**Note.** I'm fine with good lower-bounds on $I_\gamma(\lambda)$

### Solution for the extreme cases: $\lambda \to 0^+$ and $\lambda \to \infty$

For any $t > 0$, one may write
$$
\frac{t}{(t + \lambda)^2} = \frac{1}{t+\lambda} - \frac{\lambda}{(t+\lambda)^2} = \begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{t},&\mbox{ if }\lambda \to 0^+,\\ \dfrac{1}{t+\lambda}+\mathcal O(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}),&\mbox{ if }\lambda \to \infty.\end{cases}
$$

Let $m_\gamma(z) := \int \dfrac{1}{z-t}d\mu_\gamma(t)$ be the Stieltjes transform of $\mu_\gamma$. It is well-known that for all real $z>0$,
$$
m_\gamma(-z)=\frac{-(1-\gamma + z) + \sqrt{(1-\gamma+z)^2 + 4\gamma z}}{2\gamma z}
$$
be the Cauchy transform of $\mu_\gamma$.

- **Case 1:** $\lambda \to 0^+$.
  One recognizes
  $
  I_\gamma(0^+) = \lim_{\lambda \to 0^+}\int_{t_-}^{t_+}\dfrac{1}{t + \lambda}d\mu_\gamma(t) = \lim_{\lambda \to 0^+}m_\gamma(-\lambda)=\dfrac{1}{1-\gamma}.
  $
- **Case 2:** $\lambda \to \infty$. Likewise, one recognizes $I_\gamma(\infty) = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\int_{t_-}^{t_+}\dfrac{1}{t + \lambda}d\mu_\gamma(t) = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}m_\gamma(-\lambda) = 0$.

Comment: I think case 1 should be $1/(1-\gamma)$ (it should not vanish for $\gamma=0$).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Indeed, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I(\lambda)=\int_{t_-}^{t_+}\frac{\sqrt{\left(t_+-t\right) \left(t-t_-\right)}}{2 \pi   {\gamma} (t+\lambda)^2}\,dt
=\frac{-\sqrt{ {\gamma}^2+2  {\gamma} ( {\lambda}-1)+( {\lambda}+1)^2}+ {\gamma}+ {\lambda}+1}{2  {\gamma} \sqrt{ {\gamma}^2+2  {\gamma} ( {\lambda}-1)+( {\lambda}+1)^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice analytic answer (upvoted). Please could kindly add a short sentence explaining how you go the answer ? Is it via some kind of symbolic integration (wolfram, sympy, mathematica, etc.) or is there a secret table of MP-integrals hidden somewhere of which I'm not aware :)

Comment: Mathematica output

Comment: The integral is "elementary", via change of variable to a rational coordinate
on $u^2 = (t_+^2-t) (t - t_-^2)$, but cumbersome to work out by hand.
Using **mathematica** or similar packages such as **maxima** is probably
the best way to proceed, as long as you check that the formula matches 
the output of numerical integration for some representative
values of $t_\pm$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the clarification. Time to start using mathematica.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks for mentioning the opensource tool "Maxima". Just tried it at the moment, and it seems really easy to use.